# Pyapns Fault 500: 'Connection to the APNS server could not be made

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get my django app to send a push notification to an iOS device running the iOS app of this service. I am trying to use [pyapns](https://github.com/samuraisam/pyapns) to send the notifications. But I can't get it to connect to the Apple push notification server.

The service is mostly done this is the last thing that I want to get to work before I step out of beta. You can visit http://pagemove.se/ to read about the app.

Here is the log:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyapns/client.py", line 75, in wrapper return func(*a, **kw) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyapns/client.py", line 67, in wrapper return func(*a, **kw) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyapns/client.py", line 97, in notify return _xmlrpc_thread(*f_args) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyapns/client.py", line 127, in _xmlrpc_thread errback(e) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyapns/client.py", line 65, in errback_wrapper errback(e) # not an instance of UnknownAppID - nothing we can do here File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyapns/client.py", line 55, in errback raise e xmlrpclib.Fault:`

Has anybody had this problem? Can it be same thing with the .pem file? or the setup of the ubuntu-server? Can i have forgotten to open some ports in the router?

Edit

I did a test to se if the ports for apns is open. I did

```
telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```

and got

```
Trying 17.149.34.65...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I do think that the server and router are setup correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem - it's frustrating, because it *can* make the connection, the `.pem` file is likely improperly formatted.

Follow this fantastic step-by-step set of directions to generate the correct final `.pem` file:

http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Also, set passwords when you're exporting the cert and key from Keychain - I know it says you can do without, but I found setting the password to something random on export from Keychain, then following the final `openssl rsa ...` step to remove said password before concatenating the files helped fix the problems I was having.

I can't speak to an absolute certainty, but for me, it was the `.pem` files, which generated the exact error messages you're receiving above.

The final `.pem` file is text and should be formatted a *little* something like this (note that the info here is randomly generated and I repeated lines a lot):

https://gist.github.com/58f79e1cd811f62bf011

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I did chanch to another python wrapper to make it work and now all is working good.

Comment: I got the same errors from pyapns when my .pem files had a password set. Fixed using openssl command from link in answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while using pyapns...tried all the answers in this post and many others...nothing helped...so just decided to use a different library (https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs). Worked first time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem but this seems to have solved it for me.  Apparently, my `.pem` still had a password, and that was the problem.  So here I'll describe how to generate a `.pem` with no password.

This blog post outlines how to get the 2 '.pem' files (Cert and Key) you need and how to concatenate them.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12.  (You can use a password to generate the `.pem` files for now - we will strip the password later).

Here's 2 commands that will help you check if your 2 `.pem` files are ok.  This first command just checks if you can connect to APNS.

```
$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```

This second command will check if your `.pem` files are ok - you'll get a bunch of output, if you've connected successfully.  If successful, and if you input some random text, it will disconnect.  If you can't connect, it'll output an error message.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
```

After you have your concatenated `.pem`, you have to get rid of its password for pyapns.  To do this, use this command on your `.pem`.

```
$ openssl rsa -in haspassword.pem -out nopassword.pem
```

And that should be it.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error as well and in my case it resulted from having a "." in my app_id

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well and in my case it is because I missed out python-epoll library as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/samuraisam/pyapns).

I think it is also helpful to check the twistd.log in your current directory